# How to see the process flow if a BPMN process is deployed through spring boot application in flowable open-source/enterprise?

Tags: flowable

We can see the process flow of the stage is currently executing from the flowable admin/control. How we can experience the same when BPMN is deployed through spring boot app in flowable engine?

I could not find the way in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with the usage of "stage" and "process flow" since stage is a CMMN concept and it seems you are talking about BPMN.

In BPMN you can get the currently active element by searching for the executions, the following REST API will help there:
https://documentation.flowable.com/latest/assets/core-swagger/bpmn.html#/Executions/listExecutions

Keep in mind that there can be more than one active execution for a process instance, since there is branching for example through parallel gateways.

In CMMN you have a stage overview, giving the information about stages:
https://documentation.flowable.com/latest/assets/core-swagger/cmmn.html#/Case%20Instances/getStageOverview

Comment: Hi Valentin, Thanks for your quick reply.  I might have mistaken the term by stage, I actually wanted to refer to the term task(preferably user task). And yes there will be multiple active executions for a process, is there any way to visualize the process, how far the process is completed/ is the process completed or not like we can see them in flowable Control when we are using spring boot?

Comment: With the enterprise product there is a component called `@flowable/draw` which is exactly doing this. However, access to this component might depend on the contract. If you do not have access you could potentially ask the service desk for access.